# Qt Runtime Error

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt IDE.The following code is causing Microsoft Visual C++ runtime library Error. Moreover the program instead of displaying items with text "NewYork" and "London", displays "NewYork" and "Londonk" and then crashes. here is the code.

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)  // creates comments for item
{
    ui->listWidget_2->clear();

    ui->commentbutton->setEnabled(true);
                                                                                                   QFile files("E:/"+QString::number(ui->listWidget->currentRow())+"com.txt");

    if(files.exists())
    {
        if(!files.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
             QMessageBox::warning(this,"File Access!!!","The File containing data of     the Items and Comments can't be acessed",QMessageBox::Ok);
             return;
        }
        QTextStream in(&files);
        QString data(in.readLine());
        int x=0;

        QString temp;

        for(int i=0;;i++)
        {
            if(i>data.size())
                break;



            if(data.at(i)!='@' && data.at(i+1)!='#')
            {
                temp[x]=data.at(i);
                x++;
            }
            else
                if(data.at(i)=='@' && data.at(i+1)=='#')
                {
                    QListWidgetItem *itm=new QListWidgetItem;

                    x=0;
                    i++;
                    itm->setText(temp);
                    ui->listWidget_2->addItem(itm);
                }
        }
        files.close();
}
```

The program generates the Xcom.txt files properly(X is a number). The file from which I am retrieving data contains this

> NewYork@#London@#.

Comment: You need to use the debugger and find out where exactly the program is crashing.

Answer (score 3):

The logic of your code is too complex. Use [`QString.split`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#split) to get the parts you're interested in.

Example:

```
#include <QtCore>

int main(void)
{
    QString foo("NewYork@#London@#");
    QStringList parts = foo.split("@#", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    foreach(QString part, parts) {
        qDebug() << part;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your code could be reduced to something like:

```
QString data(in.readLine());
QStringList parts = data.split("@#", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
foreach (QString part, parts) {
    QListWidgetItem *itm=new QListWidgetItem;
    itm->setText(part);
    ui->listWidget_2->addItem(itm);
}
```

Comment: You are a hero of Qt programming in my eyes. I am literally very much impressed by you. I have just started learning Qt. Pray for me that i become a master of Qt programming.

Answer (score 1):

It is `if(i>=data.size())`

The runtime error is probably an assert because you go beyond the last char in your QString.